Ubuntu 24.04 won't shutdown/reboot, *sometimes*
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I have a machine that will often not reboot/shutdown. Typically, when the system is relatively fresh (I can't really quantify that further), it will be OK.
However, after an unknown period of time, if I issue either a reboot or a shutdown, it will perform all the appropriate steps as a normal shutdown. However, it will fail the actual reboot or shutdown. The console will have all the output for the shutdown steps, and then it's just sitting at a state where it's hit "system reboot.target".
Note that normally, my power button on the PC works fine. eg. pushing it once will follow the BIOS setting which is to shutdown the PC. When it is in the "hung" state, I need to hold the power button 5 seconds for it to force the power off.
I'm totally stumped. It's super frustrating as any reboot remotely when out of the house will basically brick the system until I'm back home.
I found the logs using journalctl. Here the last bit
Nov 26 12:39:41 elvis systemd[1]: Reached target umount.target - Unmount All Filesystems.
Nov 26 12:39:41 elvis systemd[1]: Stopping lvm2-monitor.service - Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
Nov 26 12:39:41 elvis systemd[1]: Stopping multipathd.service - Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller...
Nov 26 12:39:41 elvis systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 26 12:39:41 elvis systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service - Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Nov 26 12:39:41 elvis multipathd[516]: multipathd: shut down
Nov 26 12:39:41 elvis systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 26 12:39:41 elvis systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service - Create Static Device Nodes in /dev gracefully.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: multipathd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: Stopped multipathd.service - Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: multipathd.service: Consumed 36.786s CPU time, 22.2M memory peak, 0B memory swap peak.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-remount-fs.service - Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: lvm2-monitor.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: Stopped lvm2-monitor.service - Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: Reached target shutdown.target - System Shutdown.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: Reached target final.target - Late Shutdown Services.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: systemd-reboot.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: Finished systemd-reboot.service - System Reboot.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: Reached target reboot.target - System Reboot.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd-journald[457]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
Nov 26 12:39:42 elvis systemd-journald[457]: Journal stopped


maybe try to reduce the DefaultTimeoutStopSec value to e.g. 25s or less??
in the file /etc/systemd/system.conf ...

Looks like the default for DefaultTimeoutStopSec is 90s. It won't even shutdown after 5 minutes.

It's about how long to wait for the processes to finish during the system restart/shutdown. Generally speaking, after that time they are simply killed.
Read about it, maybe it will help you.
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-system.conf.html
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310146/how-do-i-skip-the-90s-timeout-in-systemd

I see that. But the current setting is 90 seconds, at which point systemd will kill all processes, yet my system still will not shut down. Setting it to 25 seconds means it will kill them sooner, but I don't see how it will address the actual issue?
